# How do I attach a css sheet to my template in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to attach a css sheet to my template in django.

I have my settings.py configured with the following lines.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
                      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
                      )
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CURRENT_PROJECT = '/home/user/Documents/my_project/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(CURRENT_PROJECT, 'static'))
```

I have my css files in path `/home/user/Documents/my_project/static/css/`

I did a `python manage.py findstatic css/test_style.css`  and it prints:

```
Found 'css/test_style.css' here:
    /home/user/Documents/my_project/static/css/test_style.css
```

I am trying to link this css file in my template as follows.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/css/test_style.css" />
```

But the DEBUG=True always prints :

```
[date time] "GET /css/test_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2127
```

Can anyone help me with this.. I tried all the documentation available(djangobook, djangoproject etc..,) and I tried solutions from other stackoverflow suggestions but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks

Comment: You just want to use `"{% static 'css/test_style.css' %}"`

Comment: Doesn't work. prints HTTP 404 @lambo477

Comment: I had a leading '/' in the path. I removed it and it seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Have you included `django.contrib.staticfiles ` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Great @KiranVemuri - I was taking another look and couldn't work out what was wrong!